# mysql_fetch_array with two conditions in a table

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have 2 tables. I want to put them into a html table (each table in a separate column). I think the mysql_fetch_array doesn't work for me with 2 conditions.

```
echo "<table id='123'>";
echo "<tr> 
<th>header</th> 
</tr><td>";
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM table1"; 
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM table2"; 
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());


while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1) && $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo "";
    echo "</td><td>";   
    echo $row1['score'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row2['score'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 
echo "</td></table> <br>";
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What conditions? (BTW your HTML is malformed)

Comment: You will have a problem if your two tables are not the same size. You would be better with a single query and a JOIN, but we need to know the name(s) of the fields which relate the two tables.